# ； の意味がわからない

Tags: bash

初歩的で申し訳ないんですが、；の意味がわかりません。
参考書に出てくるけど、シレッと登場して説明がない。
参考書の練習用プログラム内に書いてあるけど、端折っても動くこともあればエラー吐くこともある。
検索しようとしたら検索できない記号らしく、困っています

Comment: 「練習用プログラム」の対象となるプログラム言語は何ですか？

Comment: 記号としてではなく単に「セミコロン」で検索すればでてこないでしょうか？vimですので`Upward search`のことを指しているのかなと推測します。

Comment: >>quesera2
その手があった！これに気づかなかったとは私は何と愚かだったことか！

>>BLUEPIXY
/bin/bash
だと思います
曖昧でよくわからないですが！

Comment: vim なら、疑問があったら `:help` (横着して `:h` でも可) をおすすめします。検索対象が記号でもきちんとヒットします。今回の `;` についても、 `:help ;` で出てきますよ。

Comment: >>yoh2
ありがとうございます！
でも自分が使ってるのはviだからか、「sorry,no help for ；」だそうです！
ネット環境が整い次第vimにするつもりなので参考にします！

Comment: Vimとは関係ない、かつbashの話題でしたので、タグを変更しました。

Answer (score 1):

bashでしたらmanで使い方を読みましょう。英語が苦手なら、[JM Project](http://linuxjm.sourceforge.jp/)が役に立ちます。これでbashについて調べると、

> コマンドを ; で区切った場合には、これらは順番に実行されます。 シェルはそれぞれのコマンドが終了するのを順番に待ちます。

だそうです。